# Restful API throw unexpected output in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, rest, codeigniter-3, api-design

controller:

```
<?php
    require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
    use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
    class User extends REST_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }
        function country_state_get()
        {
            $this->db->select('id,name');
            $this->db->from('countries');
            $sql = $this->db->get();
            $data = $sql->result_array();
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
                $this->db->select('id,name');
                $this->db->from('states');
                $this->db->where('country_id',$row['id']);
                $sqls = $this->db->get();
                $data2 = $sqls->result_array();
            }
            $result= [
                "Country" => $data,
                "state" => $data2
            ];
            $this->response($result, 200);
        }
    }
```

unexpected output:

```
{
"Country": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Algeria"
    }
]
```

}

expected output:

```
{
"Country": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "state": ["Badakhshan", "Badghis", "Baghlan"]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Albania",
        "state": ["Berat", "Dibres", "Durres"]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Algeria",
        "state": ["Adrar", "Ain Defla", "Ain Temouchent"]
    }
]
```

}

I have to create simple country and state api using codeigniter framework. Here I am getting unexpected output as I mention above. when I hit the url on my localhost server it throw unexpected out but my expected output is different. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: post you `response` function here

Comment: `$this->response($result, 200);` @Gulshan

Comment: Try adding `[]` on `$result` variable must be  like this `$result[]= [
                "Country" => $data,
                "state" => $data2
            ];`

Comment: nothing happens only `[{"Country":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]}]` on extra bracket include

Comment: I see, you are using non array variable on your loop. Try  this: `$data2[] = $sqls->result_array();` and can you post the `$data2` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `country_state_get` function with below `function` code

```
    function country_state_get()
     {
          $this->db->select('id,name');
          $this->db->from('countries');
          $sql = $this->db->get();
          $data = $sql->result_array();
          foreach($data as $key => $row)
          {
             $this->db->select('id,name');
             $this->db->from('states');
             $this->db->where('country_id',$row['id']);
             $sqls = $this->db->get();
             $data2 = $sqls->result_array();
             $data[$key]['state'] =  $data2;
          }

        $result= [ "Country" => $data ];
        $this->response($result, 200);
}
```